# UserID is not coming for Pageviews/Transactions in Universal Analytics

Tags: universal-analytics

I am pushing UserID to dataLayer each time on page load. When I visit any page with one user as logged in I am able to catch userID for that user in GA dashboard.
Problem is, if I do not close browser and log out and then sign in with another user, All the pageviews (including previous which were with different user id) are coming up against last pushed UserID. Previous UserID is not visible in GA Dashboard.
I checked that all the time whenever page loads we push correct userID in datalayer variable.
I have also tried to change scope of UserId variable in GTM, but it didn't worked.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: UserID is the name of an actual analytics feature, not a name for some custom implementation. Can you describe what you are actually doing (I assume you write a value to a custom dimenson, but your description seems a bit off. For one thing it'S unclear how you change a variable scope in GTM).

Comment: @EikePierstorff: Sorry for the confusion. I'v checked that we can only set scope via GA dashboard only.
 My problem was, for different logins there should be a different userID. This works fine if I close the browser after logout & new login action perform only in new browser session.
i.e Session was not breaking for all pageviews/transactions if I user 2 logins without closing browser. GA was only showing all data against last sent UserID value.
I found a solution (set sessionControl to 'start' ) and observing data currently. If that works will post comment here. Thanks